# Zip Attachment > 300K CXF gives EOFException

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, cxf, jax-ws

In **production** we have published a JAX-WS webservice via CXF3.3.0 so that the client could send zip file(binary data) to us - see below an example from client request - and I have encountered an interesting error case with CXF AttachmentInInterceptor.

Perhaps its totally unrelated and the issue might be with the client - how it sends the data.
Anyways,this error occurs from time to time,precisely, if the **Content-Length** is less than 300K (typically this is the case) then we are good, however if its greater than that we usually get the below error. But, there have been 2 exceptions so far, a succcessful ~400K and ~600K content.

***(update: failed for 304K 3weeks ago and 700K on 03.18.)***

So I am lost what to look for.
Maybe you can give me some hints what to do. How to reproduce such a client request like below?

***Environment: Tomcat8.5, CXF3.3.0, SpringBoot 2.0.8***

The client request contains such a schema type:

```
<xs:element name="file" type="xs:base64Binary" xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream"/>
```

The ws code:

```
public ReportResponse sendReport(DataHandler file) {
    String result = null;
    try {
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream());
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            String content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(zipInputStream, UTF_8)); // here throws EOFException
            log.info("Content({}):\n------\n{}\n------\n", entry.getName(), content);

            result = callOtherServiceWith(content, entry.getName()).block(Duration.ofSeconds(timeout));
            log.info("Response:\n{}", result);
        }
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        log.error("Zip uncompression exception.", throwable);
        return null;
    }
    return XmlUtil.unmarshall(result, ReportResponse.class, ObjectFactory.class);
}
```

Received request from client (removed sensitive data):

```
Address: https://<url>
HttpMethod: POST
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="9e17a6ec-4170-4072-bb8b-02496ff8b5fc"; start-info="text/xml"; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<bodyMessage>"
ExchangeId: 6b3329fe-e629-4fd1-9d6b-a70809ce4dbd
ServiceName: XYService
PortName: XYServiceImplPort
PortTypeName: XY
Headers: {SOAPAction="http://<url>/soapaction", connection=Keep-Alive, content-type=multipart/related; boundary="9e17a6ec-4170-4072-bb8b-02496ff8b5fc"; start-info="text/xml"; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<bodyMessage>",Content-Length=313973, X-Client-IP=<url>, Via=blabla
Payload:
--9e17a6ec-4170-4072-bb8b-02496ff8b5fc
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <bodyMessage>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bodyMessage" <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <soapenv:Envelope>...</soapenv:Envelope>
--9e17a6ec-4170-4072-bb8b-02496ff8b5fc
Content-Disposition: attachment; name=" attachment_name"; filename=" attachment_name"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <attachment_name>

….
<Binary data(zip file) here>
…
```

The error I'm getting:

```
java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:1322)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:625)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.receive(AjpProcessor.java:587)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.refillReadBuffer(AjpProcessor.java:695)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AjpProcessor.java:1433)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:642)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:349)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
        at java.io.SequenceInputStream.read(SequenceInputStream.java:207)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
        at org.apache.cxf.attachment.MimeBodyPartInputStream.read(MimeBodyPartInputStream.java:79)
        at org.apache.cxf.attachment.DelegatingInputStream.read(DelegatingInputStream.java:93)
        at org.apache.cxf.attachment.DelegatingInputStream.read(DelegatingInputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:238)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
        at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.copyReaderToBuilder(CharStreams.java:120)
        at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toStringBuilder(CharStreams.java:178)
        at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toString(CharStreams.java:164)
        <<<< points to line 7, where I made the comment  >>>>
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor167.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor167.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor318.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:246)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:486)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1715)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The rest of the stacktrace: AttachmentInterceptor
https://gist.github.com/Klesz/fc22f02958c8be9d6524368dff640c53

Comment: Does it also happen when directly communication to apache tomcat instead of going through Apache HTTPD or IIS with ISAPI redirector? Maybe there is some missmatch with workers.properties `worker.tomcat.max_packet_size` and AJP connector `packetSize`.

Comment: Where do you set these parameters? I am not a tomcat expert, but checking the server.xml I can't see any packetSize property defined for AJP or HTTP connector in it - or what is the default value?